# cannot resolve symbol 'createDefault' in JDABuilder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, discord-jda

I am trying to set up a discord bot using intelliJ, Gradles and the JDA v4.2.0_204. I followed the instruction on: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/2%29-IntelliJ-IDEA-Setup

I wanna use the JDABuilder and I've written exactly how they wrote it in the documentation to initialize the JDABuilder Object. Here is my current sample of code including the imports (I also have auto-import enabled):

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;


public class bot {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDA api = new JDABuilder.createDefault("token").build();

    }
}
```

The problem is that it always shows an error: Cannot resolve symbol 'createDefault'

I can't find any way around this and I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Remove the `new` its a static method not a constructor.

Comment: Wow thanks i feel stupid now haha! I guess I got mixed up with all the older version of tutorials and all!

Comment: FWIW, the expression `new JDABuilder.createDefault(...)` is being interpreted as an attempt to create an instance of a nested class called `JDABuilder.createDefault`.  Which doesn't exist.