# Java: cannot find symbol. JDA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, discord-jda

Working on a bot for discord in Java (JDA of course), there was a similar problem of compilation, I’m a beginner, in half a day thinking, tell me the solution, please. IDE - Intellij IDEA (Maven)

main code:

```
package me.n1ghtsoul;


import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;

public class Bot {
    private static JDA jda;
    private static final String Token_Api = "MTEwNzcxMzEzNDUxMDIzMTYxNQ.G7NnYJ.Zcy_Ij80ey0oLivIKZ4pam6pP6A8MwG3pp4Ndk";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        botInit();
    }

    private static void botInit(){
        JDABuilder jdaBuilder = new JDABuilder.createDefault(Token_Api);

        jda = jdaBuilder.setActivity(Activity.listening("крутая музыка"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.n1ghtsoul</groupId>
    <artifactId>NullifierReworked</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-beta.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>club.minnced</groupId>
                    <artifactId>opus-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Error:

```
17:47
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class createDefault
  location: class net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder
```

Looking for answers on the forums, found a couple of tips:

1. Create jar and somehow do something with the plugin that one of the conversation participants
2. Reinstall IDE
3. Import packages and classes incorrectly

---

Actually, that’s all I’ve tried so far.  It’s all in vain.

Comment: Remove the `new` before it. And regenerate your token.

Comment: Duplicate of [*cannot resolve symbol 'createDefault' in JDABuilder*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64002664/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Delete the `new`

The method `JDABuilder.createDefault` is a static [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Calling a method returns an object.

So eliminate `new`. Use `new` only to access [constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)).

Change this:

```
JDABuilder jdaBuilder = new JDABuilder.createDefault(Token_Api);
```

… to this:

```
JDABuilder jdaBuilder = JDABuilder.createDefault(Token_Api);
```

---

You will find other examples of static factory methods in the *java.time* classes. For example, to capture today’s date:

```
 LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;  // Capture the current date as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or represent a specific date:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

---

By the way, `static` is *not* object-oriented.

A static factory method is some code (a method) attached arbitrarily to a class itself (`static`) rather than to instances (objects) of that class. You can think of this as a hack, but a handy hack, for when we want to make available some behavior without the state and other methods contained in an object.

This distinction may not be clear when starting out learning [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Do not worry about it now, but revisit the idea when you have more experience.